# iPad margin have an empty space in left and right

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I wrote a universal application and I am using size classes and auto layout . Everything seems good in iPhone but when I run it on iPad there are free spaces on the left and right margins, I don't know why they appear!!!

[image]

Comment: Did you set up your constraints to be relative to the superview margins?

Comment: did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the details of your constraints.

If you use "Margin" in First Item, select that.

[image]

After that, uncheck "Relative to Margin".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you add the constraints, make sure the "Constrain to margins" option is unchecked, like in the image below.

[image: Constraints]